# Why is the Latin title of "How the Grinch Stole Christmas" so verbose?

Tags: contemporary-latin, translation-explanation

Terence Tunberg's translation of [Dr. Seuss's *How the Grinch Stole Christmas*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0865164207) has a rather prolix title:

> *Quomodo Invidiosulus Nomine Grinchus Christi Natalem Abrogaverit*

whose literal translation is:

> *How the little envious one named Grinch repealed Christmas*

Two choices stand out:

- Substituting a diminutive adjective and explicit naming for the simple "Grinch"
- Changing "steal" to a more complicated legal term, "abrogo"

I'll be honest: I've always thought this was a terrible translation of the title, substituting 5 easily understood children's words (= 7 syllables) with a long-winded and difficult title of a treatise (= 24 syllables).

A more literal translation could be:

> Quomodo Grinchus Christi Natalem Furatus Sit.

(= 14 syllables)

My question: **Has Terence, an excellent Latinist, offered any commentary on his reasons for translating this way? What are some good reasons for opting for the longer title?**

Comment: I really don't want to elicit opinions ("right on!" "seriously?"), but some objective reasons, especially confirmed by the translator himself, in favor of the chosen route.

Comment: Lectio difficilior potior. "The more difficult reading [is] the stronger." We gotta give those little kiddos a challenge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [this article](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/1998-12-15/features/9812150025_1_theodor-geisel-grinchus-christi-quomodo-invidiosulus) from the *Chicago Tribune* that partially explains this. The short version: the Tunbergs didn't think 'Grinch' sounded very good as Latin, but they couldn't get permission to change the name, because it's such a recognizable part of the story. 'Invidiosulus nomine Grinchus' was the compromise that was reached with Dr Seuss's estate, but the Tunbergs were allowed to substitute a couple of instances of 'the Grinch' in their translation with 'Invidiosulus.'